# Why is an API introduced in Honeycomb working on Gingerbread?

Tags: android, sdk, compatibility, android-3.0-honeycomb, cyanogenmod

In the [documentation for DatabaseUtils.concatenateWhere(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#concatenateWhere%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) it is stated that it is supported from API level 11+ (HONEYCOMB). However, while testing compatibility on various devices, that on my Droid X running [Cyanogenmod 7 nightly build 98 (based on gingerbread 2.3.5)](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=nightly&device=cdma_shadow), the method call not only does not cause a crash, but works as expected.

Is this some inconsistency with my custom ROM, or can anyone else reproduce this functionality on another device that is running Gingerbread or lower? Could this be an error in the SDK documentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like an error in the documentation.

GrepCode shows that the method [exists in Android 2.3.4_r1](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#DatabaseUtils.concatenateWhere%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29).

In fact, the method exists in all versions including [1.5_r4](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java#DatabaseUtils.concatenateWhere%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29).

Comment: "In fact, the method exists in all versions including 1.5_r4." Does that mean it is safe to use it? What about devices with the first revisions of the corresponding SDKs?

Comment: Is it safe to use? It appears so - I would test on a few different API levels, but it's just performing a simple operation on two Strings. As for earlier revisions, I'm not exactly sure how these work, but I think these are only required to compile your app - the operating system itself does not have revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Android 2.3.5 was released after Honeycomb. I don't find it unreasonable that Google might have implemented certain APIs from Honeycomb to help fight fragmentation. I wouldn't count on it working in other versions of Gingerbread though, without thorough testing.